# Allowing the user to interface with std::strings while implementing a linked list internally?

Tags: c++, string, list

I'm creating a textbox for my game. Most of the string related functions in the engine I'm using use std::string* or std::string& .

Here is some of the constraints:

The rest of my Gui API returns std::string& for the getText() function, so I need to be able to return a std::string& for the text.

I implemented the textbox using std::string, and making lines of strings. The problem is that it gets slow with too much text so I instead want to use a string that is a List. Rendering I assume will be slower due to caching though. How could I implement a string class with fast insertion / removal while being able to provide a std::string and a seemingly contiguous stream of chars?

Thanks

Comment: How about some code snippet or more details? I'd guess you're either using very long texts or doing something wrong (recreating copies of strings over and over again?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you really can't; the `std::string` class is required to have contiguous storage so that the `data` member function can work correctly.  If you want to use a faster representation of a string for an editor buffer, such as a [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29), you're going to have to have the function return something of a different type.

Comment: Uhm... I seem to end up commenting a few of your questions lately, disclaimer: I am not following you! Now, in C++0x your statement is true and `std::string` requires contiguous storage, but in the current standard that is not the case. In C++03 a standard conforming implementation could use ropes (and I think some did a few years ago)

Comment: @David Rodriguez- Yup, that's totally correct.  I misread the spec.  I'll delete this post ASAP.

Comment: I don't think you really need to delete the post (I don't think you even can with it being accepted). In fact, all current implementations have contiguous storage, and the new standard will require it, so even if there is a technically imprecise *required*, the answer is good from a technical point of view (that is replacing *required* by *have* makes it correct). Also, it is the only answer that brings *ropes* into the game play, which is the reason I am upvoting it.

Comment: Superior solution:  Edit your answer to *make it correct* if OP won't change what the correct answer is.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to judge from the details being given. I'd guess you're (re-)creating too many string copies, maybe passing new objects over and over again, etc.

Reserving more space for the `std::string` in advance might help as well. It's really hard to tell without knowing any actual code.

Also are you sure your code is slow due to the string handling? Or are you recreating/drawing the whole text character by character every frame? You might want to try to cache the final text in a texture or cache your "drawing instructions" (i.e. using a vertex buffer object or a simple array to save char positions) and update those on changes only.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I didn't read your question carefully enough.  Ignore the following (sorry)

It's not useful to inherit from std::string (and even if you could, implementation details would kill you).  If you *really* want to do it, you would have to create an ABC that provides the same interface as a std::string (and then probably provide a class inheriting from it that redirects all of the calls to it to a internal std::string), change all references to std::string in your current code to that of your new class, and then create another class containing your special string.

Alternatively, you could achieve the same end using templates and specializations, and avoid the overhead of virtual calls.

In short, you can't really provide a std::string unless you construct a string on the fly from a tostdstring method or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

Here's why:  std::string and std::wstring are treated specially in third-party libraries and applications, and the linker will prefer using the MSVCP80/90.DLL versions of the routines, rather than your overrides.  By providing an alternate implementation on top of the names of the typedefs for std::string and std::wstring, you violate the One Definition Rule.  Much chaos will ensue.

In an ideal world, you might choose to use another type entirely in your API that understands the non-contiguous structure of your 'string', and this type could be **SYNTACTICALLY** compatible with std::string's 200+ member functions.  It could use delayed construction of the entire contiguous string until .data() or .c_str() is called to passing it to other API functions that take char* pointers.  In this ideal world you could then recompile every single piece of code that happens to have std::string in its interface.

In the real world, you get to change your GUI API interface to understand your string-list type.